# Implementation of Open Telemetry in ASP.NET MVC on .NET 4.7.2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, metrics, open-telemetry, .net-4.7.2, open-telemetry-collector

I want to implement Open Telemetry in my ASP.NET MVC project on .NET 4.7.2. I followed the documentation but it was only up to `global.asax.cs`

Documentation: https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/net/netframework/

I have implemented up to `global.asax.cs` but I don't know the further steps for implementation of traces, metrics, logs

How to implement logs, metrics and traces in my project and sending the logs, metrics data to azure/jaeger/Geneva(Microsoft)

Any help will be appreciated - Thanks